# Copyright law and distribution terms for public versions or derivatives

Tags: copyright, software, open-source-software, derivative-work, distribution-terms

The present question is a special case of [Can one take BSD licensed code and distribute it under GPL?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/can-one-take-bsd-licensed-code-and-distribute-it-under-gpl).

Looking recently at OpenBSD's *LibreSSL*, I've noticed that *SSLeay* that it traces its roots to (through the *OpenSSL* lineage), has had the following addendum to what otherwise looks like the standard 4-clause BSD licence:

http://bxr.su/o/lib/libssl/src/crypto/objects/obj_dat.c#52

```
 *
 * The licence and distribution terms for any publically available version or
 * derivative of this code cannot be changed.  i.e. this code cannot simply be
 * copied and put under another distribution licence
 * [including the GNU Public Licence.]
 */
```

- Is it or is it not a *NOOP*, considering the possible answers from the prior question?  (Alas, the prior question has completely conflicting answers at this point!)
- Why is *GNU Public Licence* specifically mentioned; isn't GPL already incompatible with the 4-clause BSD licence that precedes the above comment, due to the advertisement clause?

Comment: What do you mean by NOOP? And as I say on all these questions, this question could perhaps get better answers at [opensource.se] (this is no longer a request for migration, but just a reminder of the other site.)

Comment: Oh god. Both FOS and your linked questions have officially confused me.

Comment: However, for your second questions, it seems as if this addendum is 1) Not part of the license or 2) is part of the license, but is not a BSD license 3) Not necessarily at all.